# Did Maharaja Dasaratha rule Bharata only, or the complete Earth?

Tags: ramayana, kings, dasharatha

Scriptures tell that Sri Rama ruled over
the total world.

Did Dasaratha rule India (Bharata) or only Koshala or the complete Earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dashratha ruled the complete Earth.**

> [Chapter 7](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/baala/sarga7/bala_7_frame.htm), Bala Kanda, Valmiki Ramayan
>
> ईदृशैस्तैरमात्यैश्च राजा दशरथोऽनघः। 
>  उपपन्नो
> गुणोपेतैरन्व**शासद्वसुंधराम्** ॥१-७-२०॥
>
> > 20. Accompanied with such of those effectual and good-natured ministers the exalted **king Dasharatha ruled the earth**.
>
> अवेक्षमाणश्चारेण प्रजा धर्मेण रक्षयन् । प्रजानां पालनं कुर्वन्नधर्मं
> परिवर्जयन् ॥ १-७-२१ ॥ विश्रुतस्त्रिषु लोकेषु वदान्यः सत्यसंगरः । स तत्र
> पुरुषव्याघ्रः **शशास पृथिवीमिमाम्** ॥ १-७-२२ ॥
>
> > - 21, 22. He that most generous one among men, Dasharatha, while observing through spies, and to protect people righteously, and to
> >   give a good governance to them, he forsook unrighteousness and became
> >   a generous king avowed to truthfulness alone, and **thus he that
> >   Dasharatha ruled the earth,** which rulership is renowned in all the
> >   three worlds.
>
> नाध्यगच्छद्विशिष्टं वा तुल्यं वा शत्रुमात्मनः ।  मित्रवान्नतसामन्तः
> प्रतापहतकण्टकः ।  स **शशास जगद्राजा** दिवं देवपतिर्यथा ॥ १-७-२३ ॥
>
> > 23. Emperor Dasharatha has not encountered either a superior or an equal in his kingship, and to him there are many friends, subdued are
> >     his provincial kings and eliminated is thorniness by his own valour.
> >     **He thus ruled the world** like Indra would in Heaven.

Comment: If dasaratha ruled the earth, how can Ravana be the King of Lanka?

Comment: Vasundhara means Bhumi. Now how do we understand the word bhumi in context of bhupala ? Bhupala is any king. So in context of describing kings without an explicit mention of a Chakravarti and his control over the entire earth, the word is very less loaded and can mean small piece of land as well

Answer (score 1):

Dasharatha ruled only the Kosala kingdom. He didn't rule entire India or world.

1. The borders of Dasharatha's kingdom ends at Syandika River -

*The said Rama showed to Sita the land (of Kosala, the southern boundary of which was defined by Syandika river)given long ago by the king Manu to Ikshvaku and which was bounded by many territories. 2-49-14*

2. Dandakaranya was under Khara -

*"O*, darling! Here, a demon called Khara, Ravana's younger brother- who is a boaster, victorious in battle, cruel and eater of human flesh, haughty and sinful-having uprooted all the ascetics who dwell in Janasthana, is unable to endure you also."**

3. Lanka is obviously under Ravana and Dasharatha has said that he is weaker than Ravana -

*"But that Ravana depletes the valour of valorous opponents in a battle, oh, eminent sage, either with my entire forces, or with all my sons I am inadequate to grapple with all his forces, or with him, individually. [1-20-23, 24a]*

So no. Dasharatha did not rule the earth or Bharata. Those are exaggrated statements. He only ruled the Kosala kingdom centred around Ayodhya.

Comment: you can be king of a small area but still be chakravarthi for an entire region.

yudhishtir ruled indraprastha personally, but after rajasuya, he got tax from all other kings throughout Bharat.

Comment: @mar -Do you think Ravana, khara etc were paying taxes to Dasharatha ? Of course not. They were much stronger than Dasharatha. So was Vali of kishkindha. Even neighbouring regions of Ayodhya was opressed by Tataka etc.